# how to catch the error in fetch response conversion to json and do something?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch

I am using this fetch request, and there are times when the response is ok (200) but the response can't be converted to json. I'm unsure of how to catch this error, i have tried using try/catch but can't figure out exactly where those clauses should be placed. I am not a javascript expert, any advice would be appreciated!

```
fetch(url2, {
        method: 'POST',
        signal: signal,
      }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.url);
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
 });
```

this is the response I get and the error:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&ve…27%20acres%3E%3D300&outputFormat=application/json", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
qgis2web.js:416 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=sde:parcels_slim_part_view&maxFeatures=1000&CQL_FILTER=county=%27Camden%27%20acres%3E%3D300&outputFormat=application/json

index.html#:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I know the problem is that the query in the URL is not structured properly and I want to create an alert when this happens.

Comment: Can you also provide the value of response?

Comment: Are you able to console `JSON.parse(response)`?

Comment: @SookieSingh no I get similar error `qgis2web.js:432 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` because it can't parse the response.

Comment: It means it is already parsed. You don't have to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is already JSON. You can use it like this:

```
fetch(url2, {
    method: 'POST',
    signal: signal,
}).then(function(response) {
    var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
});
```

Comment: oh thank you I see that now, that is helpful and makes it easier for me to try and address the error, which is now on the var features line

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: actually this causes issues with queries I know are correct when I made this change, will try to figure out why

Comment: Well you can add an extra check for the same. First check if it is JSON or not and act accordingly.